How to write Learning Objectives at the Beginning of each chapter in a new book?
For a new book that I'm writing in LaTeX, Publisher asked me to add "Learning Objectives" at the beginning of every chapter.
I added this
\section*{\em Learning Objectives of the Chapter}

I plan to give these in a bulleted list in italics fonts.
Is it possible to change the fonts also for this preamble to each chapter?
Thanks for the bright ideas!!

There are a number of packages supporting this, where some are quite old: https://ctan.org/topic/headings . However, you can define your own objectives-section, and add it to the TOC. You may want to have a look at tcolorbox, which allows quite some customization: https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox . However, less is usually more - more or less ... // I suggest to extend your posted code a little, so we can work with your idea. Also a mockup screenshot of your intended result might help.

Well you almost there. If you use \section  instead of  \section. you have them already. Depending on the class you use, you can then change them in terms of fonts etc.

A reference image would be great. Because from what you describe it sounds like \section is unnecessary and you could simply format a line as {\itshape\bfseries\Large Learning Objectives of the Chapter} .

See also tcolorbox and \addtocontents (assuming you want the list in the TOC and not in a separate \listof).
